# Jquery Slider tutorial error

Tags: jquery, menu, slider, animated

I have been making a animated menu with [the tutorial at this link](http://bit.ly/aq3Rs8). However it will only show two items. 
I have experimented and this is what is the problem.

```
$(document).ready(function(){  

//When mouse rolls over  
$("li").mouseover(function(){  
    $(this).stop().animate({height:'150px'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'easeOutBounce'})  
});  

//When mouse is removed  
$("li").mouseout(function(){  
    $(this).stop().animate({height:'50px'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'easeOutBounce'})  
});
```

});

Comment: provide fiddle because the code looks okay. is your css correct? do you have jquery easing included? do you get an error?